# Meaning of the differential of a function, and its relationship to the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential

After having sat through a semester of Calculus, (Physics-oriented), I decided to work on my basic math and tried to learn Real Analysis (from "Analysis Course Volume II",Lima, Elon. L). I was surprised to see the differential of a function introduced between the notion of differentiability and the gradient. I thought to myself that this was rather weird since in my Calculus classes the differential had never been mentioned and instead the gradient had been presented as a sort of derivative for multivalued real functions. The author somewhat justifies this by saying that there is an isomorphism between the dual space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself, induced by the inner product, effectively favoring the more "geometrically intuitive" vector inner product as opposed to covectors acting on vectors, which makes sense. 
However, I still feel uneasy. It seems like the differential is a much more central object, and I cannot seem to be able to interpret its role in Real Analysis, as opposed to the gradient and the derivative of a function. These are the definitions that Lima gives.

- Differentiability
  A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said differentiable at a point $a$ if there exist constants $A_1,...,A_n$ such that for any vector $v=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$:
  $f(a+v)=f(a)+\sum_i^n A_i \cdot\alpha_i+r(v)$
  Where of course $A_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)$ and $\lim_{\,v\rightarrow \,0} \frac{r(v)}{|v|}=0$
- Differential
  The differential of a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point $a$ is the unique linear functional $df(a): \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of whose value at the vector v is $$df(a) \cdot v=\sum_i^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) \cdot \alpha_i$$
  Now, we can easily see that the condition of differentiability can be written as
  $$f(a+v)=f(a)+df(a) \cdot v +r(v)$$
  But I also know from studying differentiable $\mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ functions that the broader sense of the derivative is the unique linear map that best approximates the function, at a point, to be linear, which in this case, would coincide with $df(a)$? So is the differential of a function actually the derivative, and not the gradient? I mean the gradient is not a linear map so I guess that's that, but then what of the Jacobian matrix? Was it not the derivative of a function? 
  In short:
- What is the differential? Is it **the** derivative?
- If so, why are we not taught that way?

Comment: Using the definition of the derivative that you provided, the differential of $f$ at point $a$ (that is, $df(a)$) is in fact the same thing as the derivative of $f$ at $a$. (Here $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $a \in \mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be differentiable at a point $a \in \mathbb R^n$. If I recall correctly, in the book Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak, the derivative of $f$ at $a$ is a linear transformation which is denoted $Df(a)$. The Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $a$ is denoted $f’(a)$, but Spivak does not call this matrix $f’(a)$ the derivative of $f$ at $a$.

Comment: On the other hand, in Tao’s book Analysis II, the derivative of a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ at a point $a$ is a linear transformation which Tao denotes as $f’(a)$. The derivative matrix is denoted $Df(a)$ by Tao.

Comment: @littleO Thanks for your comment. I am becoming more and more convinced that the differential is the true derivative for vector-valued vector functions, and the Jacobian is merely the matrix corresponding to that linear map. All that is left is to see if it is more nuanced.